# How to reach azure blob container from pod(instead of azure file share)

Tags: kubernetes, containers, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, fileshare

I'm trying to reach Azure Blob Container from kubernetes pod without success.
When I tried with FileShare it works as expected(when I change to Blob Container it fails)
My kubernetes settings:

```
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: test-data-proccessing 
    azureFile:
      secretName: azure-secret-file-share
      shareName: fileshare-test
      readOnly: false
  
  # In the container spec part
  template:
  - name: some-deployment
    container:
      volumeMounts:
        mountPath: /data
        name: test-data-proccessing
```

Did you face similar issue?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Azure Blob Storage CSI driver for Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver). [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver/blob/master/deploy/example/e2e_usage.md) is a basic usage guide.

Comment: Thanks, for your advice. I will give it a try. 

Now there is a workaround. Simply by added additional step to script, which is azcopy to sync data between conatainer(where we need them) and fileshare(where my solution works). It was the easiest way I found to use container's data.